# Are there any gems which will batch updates to an object in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am relatively new to RoR. In my RoR project I need a mechanism to queue/delay updates to an object until a certain time period expires and then all the updates are written at once. The idea is something similar to that in Basecamp and many other websites where you have a time period to re-edit your changes. I am wondering if there is a gem which can add this sort of functionality and if not what would be the best technique to use. We could build some staging tables for our objects and check these periodically. We are using vestal_versions for revision control and I am not interested in the intermediate changes if a re-edit occurs. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delayed Job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) seems like a perfect candidate.